# Error in HIbernate (xml core) program. I already added log4j jar file.

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, log4j

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:120)
        at com.hibernate.hbproject.CHibernateUtil.<clinit>(CHibernateUtil.java:12)
        at com.hibernate.hbproject.client2.main(client2.java:14)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
        and 3 more.
```

I got the error in **xml core** program.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

Add commons-logging-xxx.jar to your classpath. 
Maven dependency is the following:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where to write above code?  I am a beginner in Hibernate

Comment: Do you use maven? If yes then put it under dependencies in your .pom file